# Retain the state of checkbox status

Tags: jquery

I have a question , checkboxes that were selected were lost when clicked on menu bar . If Snacks is selected

Snacks ---->Puffs --->Veg---> and check any checkbox

And finally then if we Click on Beverages .

The issue is that the checkboxes that were selected under Snacks aren't being rembered .

Please see the jsfiddle here

http://fiddle.jshell.net/K646y/4/

Please let me know how can it remember the checkboxes selected in this case ??

Comment: Are you creating checkboxes dynamically each time the checkboxes are shown?

Comment: yes , creating them dynamically .

Comment: You might agree that you need to store the status of checkboxes when it is clicked. And insert the string `checked` into `<input>` tag when you create them dynamically.

Comment: yes correct , i need to do that .

Comment: But the issue here is that , how can i remember the selected ones ??

Comment: You can try one of the following: server side with the help of `ajax`, or in the browser with any of the following: `localStorage`, `sessionStorage`, `cookies` or simply storing the checked boxes as hidden inputs in a different part of your html ... I would recommend looking into `localStorage` as it helps with both your issue and might help you in other future similar ones

Comment: I think you're going to have problems because you are using random ids for the checkboxes so everytime the checkbox is recreated you are assigning it a new id.  Is there anyway to pass through a static id with the json data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess what you would like to do is something like this:
DEMO: http://fiddle.jshell.net/9rJpJ/7/

In your code:

```
random_number += 1;
....
"<input type='chackbox' id='"+random_number+"'  ..>"
```

This means `id` is not static and not convenient to store the chackbox statuses.
So I changed to static using loop counter `i` and `k`:

```
 var cb_id = 100*(i+1) + k;
 ....
 "<input type='chackbox' id='"+cb_id +"'  ..>"
```

And to save status when the ckeckboxes are clicked:

```
// declare variable in the global scope.
var cbstatus = {}; 

// set event handlers
$('.checkboxclas').click(function(){
    var cbid=$(this).attr('id');
    var status = $(this).prop('checked');
    cbstatus[cbid] = status;
    console.log(cbstatus);
});
```

And when you create checkboxes, you can go like this:

```
  var str_checked = "";
  if(cbstatus[cb_id]){
      str_checked = "checked";
  }
 ....
 "<input type='chackbox' id='"+cb_id +"'  "+str_checked+">"
```

Hope this helps.